# SCALA regex: Find matching URL rgex within a sentence

Tags: regex, scala

```
        import java.util.regex._


object RegMatcher extends App {
val str="facebook.com"

  val urlpattern="(http://|https://|file://|ftp://)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?"
  var regex_list: Set[(String, String)] = Set()

  val url=Pattern.compile(urlpattern)
  var m=url.matcher(str)

  if (m.find()) {


    regex_list += (("date", m.group(0)))

    println("match: " + m.group(0))

  }
  val str2="url is ftp://filezilla.com"

  m=url.matcher(str2)
  if (m.find()) {

    regex_list += (("date", m.group(0)))

    println("str 2 match: " + m.group(0))

  }
  }
```

This returns

```
match: facebook.com
str 2 match: url is ftp:
```

How do I manage the regex pattern so that both the strings are matched well.
What do the symbols actually mean in regex. I am very new to regex. Please help.

Comment: have you tried regex101 yet?  I'm pretty good at regular expressions, but https://regex101.com/ still strikes me as a really great resource.

Answer (score 0):

I read your regex as:

- 0 or 1 (`?` modifier) of the schemes (`http://`, `https://`, etc.)
- followed by  0 or 1 instance  of `www.`,
- followed by 1 or more (`+` modifier ) alphanumeric characters ,
- followed by any character ( `.` is a regex special character, remember, standing for any one character),
- followed by 0 or more (`*` modifier) alphanumerics,
- followed by any character (`.` again)
- followed by 3 lowercase letters (`{3}` being an exact count modifier)
- followed by 0 or 1 of any character (`.?`)
- followed by one or more lowecase  letters.

If you plug your regex into regex101.com, you'll not only see a similar breakdown ( without any errors I might have made, though I think i nailed it), and you'll also have a chance to test various strings against it.  Then, once you have your regexes working the way you want, you can bring them back to your script.  It's a solid workflow for both learning regexes and developing an expression for a particular purpose.

If you drop your regex and your inputs into regex 101, you'll see why you're getting the output you see.  But here's a hint: when you ask your regular expression to match `"url is ftp://filezilla.com"`, nothing excludes `"url is"` from being part of the match.  That's why you're not matching the scheme you want.  Regex101 really is a great way to investigate this further.

Comment: I understood. But now how I restrict it's usage for url type string? As in, how do I make that url is.. go away

Comment: Yes I did, but I am aware about the regex patterns thus I am not able to add the constraint to my regex.

Comment: ah then, I'd recommend you save your regex101 regex, update your answer with that link.  And likely, somebody here, maybe even me if you give me a head's up, will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The regex can be updated to

```
((ftp|https|http?):\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})
```

This is all I needed.

Comment: Are you sure you want `http?` this is matching `htt` or `http`. Why are you repeating same regex in each part of alternative? It could be reduce a lot.